# Вставка изображения в TextView (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-drawable

Пытаюсь вставить изображение в **TextView**. По нажатию на кнопку выполняется следующий код:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_CODE);
```

После чего пользователь выбирает изображение и оно должно отобразиться в элементе **TextView**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_CODE) {
            Uri imgURI = data.getData();
            Drawable drawable;
            try {
                drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(imgURI.getPath());
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);
                noteBody.setCompoundDrawables(drawable, null, null, null);
            } catch (NullPointerException ex){
                Toast.makeText(this, "По какой-то причине не удалось найти изображение. Попробуйте снова.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            //Toast.makeText(this, "Success!\n" + imgURI.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Abort operation", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

В строке `drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(imgURI.getPath());` объект `drawable` становится `null`. В чём проблема? Или получаемый путь от *imgURI* не подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую пованговать. У вас вылетает исключение `FileUriExposedException`

С недавних пор, `Uri` файла/изображения полученного из файлового браузера положено оборачивать в `FileProvider`, иными словами uri типа `file:///` теперь под запретом, должно быть что-то типа `content:///`

[Подробнее здесь](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html)

**Update**

С учетом, того, что `content://` может указывать не на физический файл, а запись в БД или сетевой ресурс, так что вам надо превращть `Uri` в `Drawable` другим способом, например так:

```
InputStream is=getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
Drawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
```

Comment: Вылетало NullPointerException в строке drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50) . К тому же во время отладки я чётко видел, что путь полученный в imgURI.getPath() начинался с "content://".

Comment: Ну все правильно. Значит вам надо научиться теперь `content://` превращать в реальный путь - вы на верном пути!

Comment: Вообще я предполагаю что путь полученный в imgURI.getPath() не подходит для Drawable.createFromPath("путь"), но в документации не указано как он должен выглядеть.

Comment: Вообще `content://` может указывать не на физический файл, а запись в БД или сетевой ресурс, так что вам надо превращть `Uri` в `drawable` другим способом

Comment: см. апдейт ответа

Comment: Хорошо, но как работать с Bitmap? Я искал решение для для вставки изображения в TextView и везде предлагают использовать объект типа Drawable. Есть ли возможность конвертировать Bitmap в Drawable? Или можно использовать Bitmap чтобы вставить в TextView?

Comment: Ну вы даете... см. обновление

Comment: Спасибо. Возможно последний вопрос и кажется глупым, но я только учусь.